# Trigger an event when contenteditable change? (vuejs)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm looking for `vuejs` solution, for an event when contenteditable is changed. As I understand, `v-model` is only for the *inputs*, *textarea*, and other *form inputs*.

I tried using `v-model` and `v-html`, but as expected, it doesn't change the `description(data)` whenever I change the content.

```
<div class="form-control" v-html="description" v-model="description" contenteditable>{{ description }}</div>
```

Someone knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`v-model` doesn't work with `div`. But you can apply it to a component.

You can check it here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model

> Limited to:
>
> ```
> <input>
> <select>
> <textarea>
> components
> ```